# Why do I keep getting ModuleNotFoundError when I have already installed Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I just downloaded Kivy 2 on my Macbook. It showed the ModuleNotFoundError.

Since I am quite new to all these software, I decided to try using Kivy 3 instead but it showed the same error as can be seen below.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjX1u.png)

Comment: when you say you "downloaded Kivy 2" what do you mean?  how much of https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-osx.html did you follow?

Comment: I followed all the instructions. I clicked into the index of downloads and clicked into the latest version which is 1.10.1/. There was a whole list of items and I wasn't sure whether I was meant to download all or just a certain one. I then downloaded Kivy-1.10.1_osx10.13.5_builtin_python2_r1.dmg (which was called Kivy 2). I did instructions 2-5. When it didn't work, I downloaded Kivy-1.10.1_osx10.13.5_packaged_python3.6.5_r1.dmg (which was called Kivy 3). I then repeated instructions 2-5. Please do tell me if I'm doing something wrong as I'm really lost and confused. Thank you!

Comment: that's a good start!  what did you do to bring up the Python interpreter?

Comment: I have the python software on my mac so I just ran the code and the interpreter came on (im assuming this is what you are asking about as i'm not sure)